# Cut circle on the corner of box

Tags: html, css

I want to remove most of the circle and only show the part of the circle that overlaps a square:

[image: That's the image]

I need to cut the red area and leave the darker green area inside the box.

I have a class named circle with a style

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
```

and a box with style:

```
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
```

How can I remove the red area?
My code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xpVJoL

Comment: "*If you want to see my code…*" – we do, and on this site we expect you to put in the effort required to help us answer your question. Please, read both the "*[ask]*" and "*[mcve]*" guidelines.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **negative** values for position and `overflow:hidden` to hide (cut) the area :

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -50px;
  left: -50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

And if you want a more fancy way you can use `radial-gradient` as background and you will have much less code to handle :

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-image:radial-gradient(circle at bottom left, red 45%, transparent 0%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just insert `overflow:hidden;` in the `.container` class.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need another *div*, you can just do it with the `:before` or `:after` *pseudo-elements*:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: -50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```